# What happened to Reverse Flash?

Tags: character, arrowverse, the-flash

How did Eobard Thawne appear on Earth-X? I thought:

1. He got erased from existence from The Flash
2. He summoned all his time remnants in order to kill the legends only to be erased from existence yet again
3. When 1 is erased even the SPEED FORCE can't resurect him

Can someone tell me the reason behind this mystery?

Comment: I believe he was sort if resurected in season 3's Flashpoint, no ?

Comment: no i dont think so

Comment: different timelines are absolute bitches eh mate? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was previously established that there were 52 alternate "Earth's". [Arrow S06E08](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6493668/?ref_=ttep_ep8)  revealed that there are, in fact, 53. "Earth-X" is #53 and carries "no designation" because it's not 'vacation worthy' (so to speak).

So, 53 alternate Earth's would mean 53 possible story characters - right? 53 Arrows, Supergirls, and Eobard's (etc.). Just because Eobard was taken out on one Earth, wouldn't eliminate him from every Earth.

Answer (score 2):

Despite his erasure from existence, Eobard's time remnants are preserved throughout history by the Speed Force, keeping his past time travels intact in order to stabilize the timeline (where his manipulations of it span several years) and prevent further paradoxes.

Answer (score 1):

## I think he is still out there...

He was erased from existence in the first season.

But do you remember the FlashPoint in the third season where Barry goes back in time and saves his mother from being killed?

They featured the real Eobard Thawne (Not possessing Harrison's body) in the first/second episode.

Despite the fact that Barry undoes the FlashPoint, he still faces some weird outcomes (for e.g., Sarah Diggle is now Junior Johnny) of messing up with the timeline, which makes it open to think whether the 'erasing him from existing' thing even happened in the new timeline.